# source code for execve() and fork()

Tags: linux, system-calls

I would like to look at the source code for execve() and fork().Could you please tell me any websites that gives the source code and also some explaination for it.

Comment: How about http://www.kernel.org ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec()` and `fork()` both date to the early ages of UNIX, so one good place to see the code along with commentary on it is [Lions' Book](http://www.lemis.com/grog/Documentation/Lions/index.php) (a commentary on the source code for UNIX version 6).

In v6, `fork()` and `exec()` are in [`ken/sys1.c`](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/sys/ken/sys1.c).

Comment: OT: While reading Art of UNIX programming i came to know about Lion's commentary on version 6 of unix. Thanks for giving the link here

Answer (score 1):

Source can be found here: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#KMCRKdMbI4g/kernel/fork.c&q=fork&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

Comment: The link does not work